# Verifying a JWT signature using azure keyvault always returns false

Tags: c#, jwt, signing, azure-keyvault

I'm trying to verify a signature using Azure keyvault client, however it's always returning false.

I've managed to sign it using the KeyVaultClient.SignAsync method however when attempting to use KeyVaultClient.VerifyAsync the result always comes back false.

```cs
// Added for completeness, this method seems to be working correctly
private static async Task<string> SignJwt(KeyVaultClient client)
{
    var claimsToSign = new[]
    {
        new Claim("sub", "UserId123"),
        new Claim("custom", "MyValue")
    };

    var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
        issuer: "AuthApp",
        audience: "Consumer",
        claims: claimsToSign
    );

    var header = Base64UrlEncoder.Encode(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new Dictionary<string, string>()
    {
        {JwtHeaderParameterNames.Alg, JsonWebKeySignatureAlgorithm.ES256},
        {JwtHeaderParameterNames.Typ, "JWT"}
    }));

    var byteData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(header + "." + token.EncodedPayload);
    var hasher = new SHA256CryptoServiceProvider();
    var digest = hasher.ComputeHash(byteData);

    var signature = await client.SignAsync(KeyVaultBaseUrl, KeyName, KeyVersion, JsonWebKeySignatureAlgorithm.ES256, digest);

    var fullJwt = $"{header}.{token.EncodedPayload}.{Base64UrlEncoder.Encode(signature.Result)}";

    return fullJwt;
}

// This always returns a false result
private static async Task<KeyVerifyResult> ValidateJwt()
{
    // Example of a JWT produced by the SignJwt method
    var jwt = "eyJhbGciOiJFUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJVc2VySWQxMjMiLCJjdXN0b20iOiJNeVZhbHVlIiwiaXNzIjoiQXV0aEFwcCIsImF1ZCI6IkNvbnN1bWVyIn0.6tYkBcoFojJVJBhdNST49v4A3VWC1Rqizx_FzmSRICQubDEfXVopfP7Rs9tOBi9YzTCbod9o3hmHzIxANoIh7A";

    var client = new KeyVaultClient(GetAccessTokenAsync, new HttpClient());

    var jwtParts = jwt.Split('.');
    var header = jwtParts[0];
    var body = jwtParts[1];
    var signature = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Base64UrlEncoder.Decode(jwtParts[2]));

    var byteData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($"{header}.{body}");
    var hasher = new SHA256CryptoServiceProvider();
    var digest = hasher.ComputeHash(byteData);

    var verified = await client.VerifyAsync(KeyVaultBaseUrl, KeyName, KeyVersion, JsonWebKeySignatureAlgorithm.ES256, digest, signature);
    return verified;
}


private static async Task<string> GetAccessTokenAsync(string authority, string resource, string scope)
{
    var appCredentials = new ClientCredential(ClientId, ClientSecret);
    var context = new AuthenticationContext(authority, TokenCache.DefaultShared);

    var result = await context.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, appCredentials);

    return result.AccessToken;
}
```

Any ideas why ValidateJwt always returns false instead of true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it.

For anyone interested I wasn't properly base 64 encoding the signature in the SignJwt method:

Instead of using `Base64UrlEncoder.Encode/Decode`, use `Convert.ToBase64String/FromBase64String`

---

For the code snippet in the question to work, I needed to update the SignJwt and ValidateJwt methods to:

```
private static async Task<string> SignJwt(KeyVaultClient client)
{
    var claimsToSign = new[]
    {
        new Claim("sub", "UserId123"),
        new Claim("custom", "MyValue")
    };

    var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
        issuer: "AuthApp",
        audience: "Consumer",
        claims: claimsToSign
    );

    var header = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new Dictionary<string, string>()
    {
        {JwtHeaderParameterNames.Alg, JsonWebKeySignatureAlgorithm.ES256},
        {JwtHeaderParameterNames.Typ, "JWT"}
    })));

    var byteData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(header + "." + token.EncodedPayload);
    var hasher = new SHA256CryptoServiceProvider();
    var digest = hasher.ComputeHash(byteData);

    var signature = await client.SignAsync(KeyVaultBaseUrl, KeyName, KeyVersion, JsonWebKeySignatureAlgorithm.ES256, digest);

    var fullJwt = $"{header}.{token.EncodedPayload}.{Base64UrlEncoder.Encode(signature.Result)}";

    return fullJwt;
}

private static async Task<KeyVerifyResult> ValidateJwt()
{
    // Example of a JWT produced by the SignJwt method
    var jwt = "eyJhbGciOiJFUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJVc2VySWQxMjMiLCJjdXN0b20iOiJNeVZhbHVlIiwiaXNzIjoiQXV0aEFwcCIsImF1ZCI6IkNvbnN1bWVyIn0.6tYkBcoFojJVJBhdNST49v4A3VWC1Rqizx_FzmSRICQubDEfXVopfP7Rs9tOBi9YzTCbod9o3hmHzIxANoIh7A";

    var client = new KeyVaultClient(GetAccessTokenAsync, new HttpClient());

    var jwtParts = jwt.Split('.');
    var header = jwtParts[0];
    var body = jwtParts[1];
    var signature = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Convert.FromBase64String(jwtParts[2]));

    var byteData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($"{header}.{body}");
    var hasher = new SHA256CryptoServiceProvider();
    var digest = hasher.ComputeHash(byteData);

    var verified = await client.VerifyAsync(KeyVaultBaseUrl, KeyName, KeyVersion, JsonWebKeySignatureAlgorithm.ES256, digest, signature);
    return verified;
}
```

Comment: Glad you were able to resolve this! Can you mark this as the answer?

Comment: would you mind posting the complete correct code?

Comment: @Leonardo sure, I've added the sample code to my answer

Comment: What `GetAccessTokenAsync` is? Can you share a code of it?